# How do I install Python 2.7.4 OR 3.3.1 on an Amazon AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, yum, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 instance running a standard AMI, and have exhausted the limit of my abilities with yum and similar avenues to update python to 2.7.4 or 3.3.1 for a library I need to use.

Unfortunately, while I can install 2.6.X with very little effort, and 2.7.3 with only slightly more, I can't seem to find a way to get my desired version on this AMI short of compiling from source.

Is this my only route? I am not experienced enough with compiling packages from source to feel confident that will be done correctly.

Additionally, should I uninstall the older versions of Python that were added through yum before installing my desired version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

Download and compile from source.  Not that hard, then just use the #!/usr/local/bin/python or whatever location you install to.

Another option is to install/setup the EPEL repo which has the 2.7 and 3 packages and just do the yum install.

Answer (score 1):

I was very glad to see the suggestion to enable the EPEL repository for Yum.

It seems much simpler than the whole, download, unzip, compile sequence!

However, Python v.3 doesn't seem to be available in the EPEL repo, at the moment.

This how to turned up: (http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#epel)

"
How do I enable the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository?

Modify /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo. Under the section marked [epel], change enabled=0 to enabled=1.

To temporarily enable the EPEL 6 repository, use the yum command line option --enablerepo=epel.

Please note that the Amazon Linux AMI repositories are configured with a higher priority than any third-party repositories. The reason for this is because there are several packages that are part of the Amazon Linux AMI that are also in third-party repositories, and we want to make sure that the Amazon Linux AMI version is installed in the default case. 
"

which I tried immediately, via "yum search":

$  yum search all --enablerepo=epel python3

Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                        | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                     | 2.3 kB     00:00
epel/metalink                                                                                    |  12 kB     00:00
epel                                                                                             | 4.2 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                                  | 6.0 MB     00:02
656 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
epel/pkgtags                                                                                     | 998 kB     00:01
===================================================Matched: python3 ===================================================
python-apipkg.noarch : Python namespace control and lazy-import mechanism
python-futures.noarch : Backport of the concurrent.futures package from Python 3.2
python-unicodenazi.noarch : Module that finds unicode/bytestring comparisons and other problems
Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper

Great idea, but as often happens, there are snags lying in wait ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a more updated answer for AWS EC2 users as of April 2015:

As of Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03, Python 2.7 or Python 3 is supported directly by Amazon by default.  Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.4 can be installed simultaneously and are managed by the `alternatives` command.

All of this is documented clearly on the top half of:  http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.03-release-notes/